# Render Ajax's received Data in a strongly-typed view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

In my `ASP.NET MVC app`, I have an `Ajax` call that reads a record from the server and should show it in the client side. The view file is strongly typed, so I have all of the elements on the page.

How can I **render those received data on the page?** Notice that I have to use Ajax to show different data. It's kind of a `SPA application`, but I really prefer not to use `third-party libraries` unless they have a real advantage.

Action method's return looks like this:

```
var data = repoH.GetAll().Where(....).FirstOrDefault();
return Json(data);
```

and the Ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("action", "controller")',
        method: 'post',
        success: function (result) {
            debugger;
        }
    });
});
```

The view looks like this:

```
<form id="formId">
   @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
   <div class="form-group form-inline col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
         @Html.LabelFor(x => x.fieldA, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-6" })
         @Html.EditorFor(x => x.fieldA)
      </div>......
   </div>
```

With some buttons and some custom Ajax calls. I have to implement the entire CRUD operations this way!

Any suggestion is welcome! Please let me know if I got anything wrong, this app has changed several times and I'm really confused!

Comment: what does your view look like?

Comment: If you want it to updated in strongly typed fashion, I would return Partial View from controller instead json

Comment: In the success part of the ajax call just parse the result and append it as html to your page, to some target element where the data belongs to.

Comment: I have other elements on the page, so I don't suppose returning a partial view would work. @dee, How I can parse it? I want to avoid repetition, any foreach?

Comment: What make you think a partial view would not work - having other elements on the page has nothing to do with it. In the ajax success callback, just use `$('#someElement').html(result);` where `someElement` is `<div id="someElement"></div>` The partial view you return will then be inserted into that `div`

Comment: There is another thing too, they're not all in one place! I had to put other elements between them. Do I have any other solution? Because even if this works, I'll end up with a lot of partial views.

Comment: Did you get this working? Is there anything i can help you with?

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort Razvan. :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I'm working on another view now, my own approach was a real pain in the ass! I've implemented the read operation the way you suggested, with partial views, can you guide me a little about other operations as well? Any useful link is welcome, thanks. I should use Json.serialize for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand if you have the possibility to render this on the server side, but yeah.

First this `... return Json(data);` isn't really a asp.net mvc approach cause you're not returning a view.

Let's say you have this.

```
var databaseModel = repoH.GetAll().Where(....).FirstOrDefault();

/* optionally, but best practice var viewModel = map databaseModel to some viewModel */
```

Then use a method that will render your viewModel to a string.

```
  // this will be in a RenderingHelper class 
  public static string RenderViewToString(ControllerContext context, string viewName, object model)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
                viewName = context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

            ViewDataDictionary viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);

            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(context, viewName);
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(context, viewResult.View, viewData, new TempDataDictionary(), sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
```

So you will have to create a partial which accepts your viewModel (databaseModel) and then store the rendered html:

```
string renderedHtml = RenderingHelper.RenderViewToString(this.ControllerContext, "~/Views/MyController/MyPartial", viewModel);
```

And you can then return a Json which will contain the rendered html and another data as you want `{ RenderedHtml = renderedHtml, SomeData = someData }` .

And you will receive the rendered Html in your response:

```
success: function (response) {
            // test if you have response.RenderedHtml
            // and then override your container html with what you rendered on the server            $('#your_container_to_render_data_on_the_page').html(response.RenderedHtml);
        }
```

And like this you create a databaseModel(viewModel) and then render (server-side) the according partial view and then return inside json the rendered html to client-side.

I don't see other approach.

Comment: Is there any point in Angular JS? I don't really know if that is relevant to this type of problem.

Comment: You didn't specify that you have Angular. With Angular there is another approach : Web API. You always return just data from server and render view on the client-side.

Comment: I don't have Angular. I just asked if there's any point in that, since I'm not familiar with it. One more question! How long does it take to get started with Angular and Web API? I'm in the middle of a project, do you suggest learning them? I can manage it if it's less than 20 hours.

Comment: It's a totally different approach. If you are in the middle of a project best approach is to stick to that technology. If all your views are written in razor (asp.net) you will need like 10 min per view only to move them from razor to angular (client-side templates used for rendering).

Comment: And you will need like 3 hours for setup and another 1 hour for form-validation and so on. This is after you get familiar with the framework.

Comment: And Angular is using client-side routing. Mixing routes (client-side and server-side) is difficult to manage and quite strange. So this will take a lot either you choose to mix or to keep only client-side routing.

Answer (score 1):

For example you have such action which returns `json`:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetValidConnectionTypes(string code)
{
    SelectList validConnectionTypes = GetValidConnectionTypes(code);
    return Json(validConnectionTypes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And in the view you have javascript function where you call this action via ajax and receivies the result as `data`:

```
function loadValidConnectionTypes(code) {
    $deferred = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
        url: getValidConnectionTypesUrl,
        data: { code: code },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET"
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        var items = "";
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
        });

        var selectItem = $("#ConnectionType");
        selectItem.html(items);

        $deferred.resolve();
    })
    .fail(function (r, s, e) {
        $deferred.reject();
    });

    return $deferred.promise();
}
```

Then in the `done` part just parse the `data` by creating a html (like in the example `<option></option>`) and append it to the page (`selectItem.html(items)`). HTH

Comment: Thanks, but I have a lot of elements, it not just one of them. And they're from different types.

Comment: Well, this is just an example how 'in general' it could be done. Or you could return complete html from the action as well, not json. Means to create partial view and return it from the action as html.